# How do I get Citrix Xendesktop to treat every client login as a unique Windows session?

Tags: citrix, windows-users, xendesktop

I work at a moderately sized company and we currently have Citrix Xendesktop 7 tied in with our AD and domain. We have 25 clients we're having employees test right now via the Web Storefront.

Everyone can log in with their domain credentials fine enough, but the image treats every session as if it is a brand new Windows session whenever they first log in for the day (First-time user prompts for Adobe Acrobat, Word Processor, no initial file associations, etc).

Besides having everyone log directly into the main desktop image to save their profile, how would I go about configuring the applications so they don't treat everyone as a brand new user during each session? (I remember someone saying this could be accomplished through the registry settings but I couldn't pull the thread back up for reference).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest Citrix UPM and use group policy for folder redirection. You may just need to configure the settings for your environment. You can then have mandatory or unique profiles set.

[XD 7 User Profiles](http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/xendesktop-7/cds-manage-profiles.html)

[Folder Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275.aspx)